# How to Prove the Binomial Series by Differentiation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

> (a) Let $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{k}{n} x^n$. Differentiate this series to show that $$g'(x) = \frac{kg(x)}{1+x}, \quad -1 < x < 1.$$
> (b) Let $h(x) = (1+x)^{-k} g(x)$ and show that $h'(x) = 0$.
>
> (c) Deduce that $g(x) = (1+x)^k$.

For part (a), I'm getting $g'(x) = g(x) \frac{n}{x}$. How did they get $g'(x) = \frac{kg(x)}{x+1}$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Also, please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: Please use [MathJax])https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=mathjax+tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) to format the formulas in your MSE posts and avoid using images whenever possible. As for the mathematics, $n$ is a bound variable in the definition of a sum, so you can't bring it out as if it were a parameter of the problem.

Comment: Maybe consider $g'(x)(1+x)$? Sometime you can use back the result to guess how can you derive the result. And also your $n$ is depending on the index, so you cannot write it without the summation.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us how you calculated that derivative we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
g(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{k}{n} x^n \\
\implies g'(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \binom{k}{n} x^{n-1}.
\end{align*}
Note that, as you've done, you can't pull $n$ out the sum here. $n$ is a dummy variable; $g'(x)$ cannot depend on $n$. Instead, note \begin{align*}
(1+x) g'(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(n \binom{k}{n} x^{n-1} + n \binom{k}{n} x^n\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n k!}{(k-n)! n!} x^{n-1} + \frac{nk!}{(k-n)! n!} x^n\right) \\
&= k \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\binom{k-1}{n-1} x^{n-1} + \binom{k-1}{n-1} x^n\right) \\
&= k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \binom{k-1}{n} x^n + \binom{k-1}{n-1} x^n\right)
\end{align*}
by reindexing the first term. But by [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule), we obtain
$$(1+x)g'(x) = k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom kn x^n = kg(x).$$

Comment: This is correct (and accepted) but I think you should have waited until the OP showed more work before answering.